# Making a matrix Toeplitz

Tags: matrices, inverse, toeplitz-matrices

If $A$ is a Hermitian square matrix, then can we say the following is a Toeplitz matrix?

$$\mathrm{diag}(A)^{-1/2} A\, \mathrm{diag}(A)^{-1/2}$$

Or, in other words, what condition $A$ has to satisfy so the resulting would be Toeplitz?

Comment: A [Toeplitz matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix) has a very special form, that is not likely to be obtained by just multiplying rows and columns of a general hermitian matrix by some coefficient. It shouldn't be too difficult to find a counterexample.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes but I don't know why in my Matlab code resulting matrix is always Toeplitz. Actually, A is the covariance matrix.  I can't understand what property it has to make it Toeplitz!

Comment: Well, try with this, first example I picked randomly. $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3\\2 & 1 & 1\\3 & 1 & 4\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Of course it doesn't work either with variance matrices, in general. If it leads to a Toeplitz matrix in your case, and if it's not a coding error, then, maybe your dataset is designed in such a way that the variance matrix has this property. You will have to tell us more about your data.

Comment: When working with $n \times n$ Hermitian matrices, one has $\binom{n+1}{2} = \frac{(n+1) n}{2}$ degrees of freedom. When working with $n \times n$ Toeplitz matrices, one has $2n-1$ degrees of freedom.

Comment: Thanks a lot for comments. I checked my original covariance matrix is generated by a ULA channel model (in the field of communication), so it is always Toeplitz. that's why it happened.